# Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for connection type "hlfv1" when Generating an Angular 4 application

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm following [this tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html) on MacOS.

At Step 5, output of **composer-rest-server**:

```
Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Rest Server dynamic logging is enabled
Unhandled error for request GET /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png: Error: Cannot GET /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
```

**http://localhost:3000/explorer**:

```
Unhandled error for request GET /explorer: Error: Cannot GET /explorer
```

composer -v, composer-rest-server -v: v0.20.1

**http://localhost:3000/status/**:

```
{"started":"2018-09-22T14:54:49.274Z","uptime":495.566}
```

At Step Six: Generating an application I get the error messages:

```
$ yo hyperledger-composer:angular
Welcome to the Hyperledger Composer Angular project generator
? Do you want to connect to a running Business Network? Yes
? Project name: angular-app
? Description: Hyperledger Composer Angular project
? Author name: JPS
? Author email: jps
? License: Apache-2.0
? Name of the Business Network card: admin@tutorial-network
? Do you want to generate a new REST API or connect to an existing REST API?  Connect to an existing REST API
? REST server address: http://localhost
? REST server port: 3000
? Should namespaces be used in the generated REST API? Namespaces are not used
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for connection type "hlfv1". Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown
Found: [node-v59-darwin-x64-unknown]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
Original error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-hyperledger-composer/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node'-Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown
Found: [node-v59-darwin-x64-unknown]
```

I ran **npm rebuild** already.

Comment: The explorer interface is at 127.0.0.1/explorer (if it is running locally on your machine). The explorer interface is a development time web interface to help explore the capabilities of the rest server

Comment: I added the output of compose-rest-server and http://localhost:3000/explorer at step 5 above.

Comment: Did you answer `No` to the question `Specify if you want to enable the explorer test interface:` ? if you did then you disable the explorer interface and you need to either use something like curl, postman or invoke the rest apis from your application rather than use the developer explorer interface

Comment: yes, so I re-ran composer-rest-server with Yes, explorer is visible now. Thx. Still I have the error at step 6.

Comment: Step 6 is reporting a version mismatch with levels of node. Try deleting the directory generated by Yo and starting again. If that doesn't work. Then I recommend removing node completely and starting again, and do not install node as root user, but use nvm to manage you node installation as your logged in user. Our tutorials and installation guides explicitly state not to install node as root.

Comment: ok, will skip step 6 then, thx

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with your composer-client module, just uninstall it.

```
npm uninstall -g composer-cli@0.20
```

Now install it as globally. Make sure you are **non root user**. Run the below command without `sudo`.

```
npm install -g composer-cli@0.20
```

> ***Note***: Here I'm using version 0.20, install your compatible version.